# Seletor radio PHP/Bootstrap não funciona

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, aplicação-web

Conseguem me explicar por que o código abaixo não funciona? Está dando erro quando executo.

Apresenta o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código no pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/6pH5AW4i

Comment: A variavel `$sexo` não está inicializada

Comment: Sabe como corrigir? Sou bem noob quanto a isso...

Comment: Você pode adicionar mais uma condição no seu if  `(!empty($sexo) &&  $sexo=="F" )`

Comment: basta declarar a variável sexo no inicio do PHP `<?php $sexo=''; ?>`

Comment: De onde vem o valor da variável sexo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso você pode usar a função "**isset**" para testar se a variável existe:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo" value="M" <?php echo isset($sexo) && $sexo == "M" ? "checked" : null; ?>/> Masculino
```

Porém, o mais comum nestes casos é desabilitar alguns erros do PHP para que esse tipo de aviso não fique disparando. Para isso você precisa adicionar algumas exceções no seu arquivo "**php.ini**".

Também é possível desabilitar estes erros chamando esta function:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!!